# Using an Image as a Link in AsciiDoc

Tags: html, hyperlink, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I'm trying to create a "clickable" image in AsciiDoc lightweight markup language with [Asciidoctor](http://asciidoctor.org).

I tried the following (not working):
`image::<url1>[<url2>[]]`

For example:

```
image::https://img.shields.io/badge/License-Apache%202.0-blue.svg[http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0[]]
```

It should become roughly the following html:

```
<a href="http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"><img src="https://img.shields.io/badge/License-Apache%202.0-blue.svg"></a>
```

How can I accomplish this in AsciiDoc without passing through raw HTML?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

block:

```
image::https://img.shields.io/badge/License-Apache%202.0-blue.svg[link="http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"]
```

inline:

```
image:https://img.shields.io/badge/License-Apache%202.0-blue.svg[link="http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"]
```

Notice the `link` attribute on the image.

Comment: This also works for relative links as well

`image:static/researchtab.png[link="static/researchtab.png"]`

Comment: And it's a good idea to include an alt attribute for images `image:foo.jpg[link="bar.html" alt="Picture of a Foo"]`.

Comment: @DaveGauer, this can also be rewritten as `image:foo.jpg[Picture of a Foo,link="bar.html"]`